# Given Products, each with multiple Versions, what is the preferred/best way to support custom attributes at the Product/Version level in my Django app

Tags: python, django

I'm building my first Django app to manage multiple SaaS products.

This entails storing custom attributes for each Version of each Product.

For example, a new version of a Product is released that includes new configuration options that the earlier versions of the Product do not support.

I need to be able to keep track of those new values for each instance of the new Version.

I'm thinking I want the Admins to be able to add "custom fields" at the Product level by Version.

Looking for suggestions as to the best approach.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decide to go with sub-classes with each Product as each has a limited set of specific attributes that won't change much or at all over time. Thanks for all the great feedback. Learned a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

The common way of tracking model versions is to use [django-reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like each instance needs its own custom attributes. That means that changing the Models relating to Product and Version need not occur. This is good, because models can only change with the code (unless you get into dynamically generating Models which is usually not a good idea).

So, you need to be able to model attributes for each Product instance, regardless of Version. This should be a simple data modelling exercise, not necessarily related to Django.

1. A Product has a set of fields
2. A Product has a Version
3. A Product has a set of Attributes

This is quite easily modelled, depending on how you want to manage attributes.

```
class Version(models.Model):
    version = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class ProductAttributes(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    # other fields as necessary

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    version = models.ForeignKey(Version)
    attributes = models.ManyToManyField(ProductAttributes, related_name='products')
```

That should be your modelling sorted in a very basic way. Now, let's create some instances.

```
v1 = Version(version='1.0.0')
v1.save()
hosted = ProductAttributes(name='Hosted', description='We host the apps!')
hosted.save()
shiny = ProductAttributes(name='Shiny', description='I like shiny')
shiny.save()
p = Product(name='Web Based Email', version=v1)
p.save()
p.attributes.add(hosted)
p.attributes.add(shiny)

p.attributes.all()
# shows shiny and hosted!
```

You can tweak the ModelAdmin for Product such that you can add ProductAttributes inline when adding or editing a Product. You can also have a separate ModelAdmin for ProductAttributes so you can create a list of known Attributes that can be applied to products at a later date.

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic approaches for this.

1. Use a document based db (ie, "NoSQL") like Couch or Mongo. These have flexible schemas, so allow for multiple variations on a product.
2. Use the Entity Attribute Value ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model)) schema pattern. [django-eav](https://github.com/mvpdev/django-eav) is an app that provides this.

Comment: So django-eav looks promising but I left something out that has me a bit confused. 

I need to be able to "define" a custom attribute at the Version level and then actually "store/track" values at the Instance level. 

By that I mean I will have several instances of applications for each Version. 

So if I define new attribute X for Version Y then every Instance that is of that Version Y will need values for attribute X, but an Instance of Version Z will not.

Make sense?